# Set Fan Speed on Windows in C++

Tags: c++, windows, hardware, wmi

I have this copied code from [Example: Calling a Provider Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390421%28VS.85%29.aspx), it modified it now should it change CPU fan speed:

```
#define _WIN32_DCOM

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <comdef.h>
#include <Wbemidl.h>

# pragma comment(lib, "wbemuuid.lib")

int main(int iArgCnt, char ** argv)
{
    if(IsDebuggerPresent())cout<<"Debugee?\n";
    HRESULT hres;

    // Step 1: --------------------------------------------------
    // Initialize COM. ------------------------------------------

    hres =  CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED); 
    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize COM library. Error code = 0x" 
             << hex << hres << endl;
        return 1;                  // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 2: --------------------------------------------------
    // Set general COM security levels --------------------------
    // Note: If you are using Windows 2000, you must specify -
    // the default authentication credentials for a user by using
    // a SOLE_AUTHENTICATION_LIST structure in the pAuthList ----
    // parameter of CoInitializeSecurity ------------------------

    hres =  CoInitializeSecurity(
        NULL, 
        -1,                          // COM negotiates service
        NULL,                        // Authentication services
        NULL,                        // Reserved
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,   // Default authentication 
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // Default Impersonation  
        NULL,                        // Authentication info
        EOAC_NONE,                   // Additional capabilities 
        NULL                         // Reserved
        );


    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize security. Error code = 0x" 
             << hex << hres << endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;                      // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 3: ---------------------------------------------------
    // Obtain the initial locator to WMI -------------------------

    IWbemLocator *pLoc = NULL;

    hres = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_WbemLocator,             
        0, 
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
        IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID *) &pLoc);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to create IWbemLocator object. "
             << "Err code = 0x"
             << hex << hres << endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;                 // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 4: ---------------------------------------------------
    // Connect to WMI through the IWbemLocator::ConnectServer method

    IWbemServices *pSvc = NULL;

    // Connect to the local root\cimv2 namespace
    // and obtain pointer pSvc to make IWbemServices calls.
    hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(
        _bstr_t(L"ROOT\\CIMV2"), 
        NULL,
        NULL, 
        0, 
        NULL, 
        0, 
        0, 
        &pSvc
    );

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Could not connect. Error code = 0x" 
             << hex << hres << endl;
        pLoc->Release();     
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;                // Program has failed.
    }

    cout << "Connected to ROOT\\CIMV2 WMI namespace" << endl;


    // Step 5: --------------------------------------------------
    // Set security levels for the proxy ------------------------

    hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(
        pSvc,                        // Indicates the proxy to set
        RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT,           // RPC_C_AUTHN_xxx 
        RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE,            // RPC_C_AUTHZ_xxx 
        NULL,                        // Server principal name 
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL,      // RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_xxx 
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_xxx
        NULL,                        // client identity
        EOAC_NONE                    // proxy capabilities 
    );

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Could not set proxy blanket. Error code = 0x" 
             << hex << hres << endl;
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();     
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;               // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 6: --------------------------------------------------
    // Use the IWbemServices pointer to make requests of WMI ----

    BSTR MethodName = SysAllocString(L"SetSpeed");
    BSTR ClassName = SysAllocString(L"CIM_Fan");

    IWbemClassObject* pClass = NULL;
    hres = pSvc->GetObject(ClassName, 0, NULL, &pClass, NULL);

    IWbemClassObject* pInParamsDefinition = NULL;
    hres = pClass->GetMethod(MethodName, 0, 
        &pInParamsDefinition, NULL);

    IWbemClassObject* pClassInstance = NULL;
    hres = pInParamsDefinition->SpawnInstance(0, &pClassInstance);

    // Create the values for the in parameters
    VARIANT varCommand;
    varCommand.vt = VT_BSTR;
    varCommand.bstrVal = L"10";

    // Store the value for the in parameters
    hres = pClassInstance->Put(L"CommandLine", 0,
        &varCommand, 0);
    wprintf(L"The command is: %s\n", V_BSTR(&varCommand));

    // Execute Method
    IWbemClassObject* pOutParams = NULL;
    hres = pSvc->ExecMethod(ClassName, MethodName, 0,
    NULL, pClassInstance, &pOutParams, NULL);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Could not execute method. Error code = 0x" 
             << hex << hres << endl;
        try{
        VariantClear(&varCommand);
        SysFreeString(ClassName);
        SysFreeString(MethodName);
        pClass->Release();
        pInParamsDefinition->Release();
        // pOutParams->Release();
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();     
        CoUninitialize();
        }
        catch(...){
            cout<<""; // NOTHING
        };
        system("pause");
        return 1;               // Program has failed.
    }

    // To see what the method returned,
    // use the following code.  The return value will
    // be in &varReturnValue
    VARIANT varReturnValue;
    hres = pOutParams->Get(_bstr_t(L"ReturnValue"), 0, 
        &varReturnValue, NULL, 0);


    // Clean up
    //--------------------------
    VariantClear(&varCommand);
    VariantClear(&varReturnValue);
    SysFreeString(ClassName);
    SysFreeString(MethodName);
    pClass->Release();
    pInParamsDefinition->Release();
    pOutParams->Release();
    pLoc->Release();
    pSvc->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this, it not work. What I should change?

Comment: Is it a good idea to play with the CPU fan speed? Also please post any error messages if any?

Answer (score 0):

Fan speed control via WMI is going to be pretty vendor-specific; there are no general controls for CPU/mainboard fans (though WMI is what people *should* be doing). Also, this would be **way** easier in PowerShell or even C# than trying to use C++ to play with WMI stuff. At least figure out how to do it in PSh first, then transcribe it to C++